# TypeError: Mongo.collection is not a function

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

I'm new in Meteor. trying to build an app. When I'm adding this line of code: 
   
 `export const Work = new Mongo.collection("work");`
 to the file it giving this error:

> W20170524-18:21:28.376(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/yusifkhalilov/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.4_2.1sgods7++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.377(-7)? (STDERR)                                            throw(ex);
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.377(-7)? (STDERR)                                            ^
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.377(-7)? (STDERR) 
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.377(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: Mongo.collection is not a function
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.378(-7)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.server.main.js (server/main.js:5:21)
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.378(-7)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.378(-7)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:120:16)
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.379(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/yusifkhalilov/Documents/work/moving_company/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:52:1
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.379(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/yusifkhalilov/Documents/work/moving_company/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:303:34
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.379(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.379(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/Users/yusifkhalilov/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.4_2.1sgods7++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.379(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/yusifkhalilov/Documents/work/moving_company/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.379(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/yusifkhalilov/Documents/work/moving_company/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:352:5
>   
> W20170524-18:21:28.379(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/yusifkhalilov/Documents/work/moving_company/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)

Comment: is  Mongo.Collection with "C"

Comment: no with "c" Mongo.collection

Comment: It worked Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB is case sensitive. use a Capital "c" at your collection. your code must be

export const Work = new Mongo.Collection("work");

Comment: Thank you! it worked after "C"

Comment: No prob. Enjoy :) Give rep please.

Comment: I can't. :( my status not giving. I will asap